# How to determine is wsl2 is running from an IntelliJ terminal in windows?

Tags: windows, zsh, wsl2, intellij-idea

I have some settings in my `.zshrc` file that should run in a regular terminal, but not when the terminal is called from IntelliJ.

I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 Ultimate Edition on Windows 11, and I am using wsl2 version 2.1.5.0.

Basically, I don't want `tmux` to launch in an IntelliJ terminal, so I used the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393178/prevent-tmux-from-starting-in-intellij-terminal).

In order to do that, on a normal Linux machine, I have added the following block to my rc file :

```
if ps -p $PPID | grep -iq java; then
#config for intelliJ execution
else
#config for regular execution
fi
```

However, the problem on wsl2 is that both commands `ps -p $PPID` return the same output and that `ps aux` doesn't show any java process on either terminals. This makes sense, as IntelliJ is a windows process, and wsl2 has no knowledge of its existence.

I also know that IntelliJ sets the variable `TERMINAL_EMULATOR` to `JetBrains-JediTerm` when invoking a new shell. However, for my version at least, the allocation does not work out of the box for wsl.

Here are the steps I tried to circumvent the issue :

- I set up my environment variables and updated WSLENV=TERMINAL_EMULATOR in my windows settings

  - I can retrieve the value of the variable in my IntelliJ terminal. The problem is that the value is global to the system, so any new terminal I open will have the value defined.
- In the `Tools>Terminal` section of the IntelliJ settings, I tried updating the `Shell path` value to `wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-22.04 zsh -c "isIntellij=true zsh"`

  - This works with bash (when writing `wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-22.04 bash -c "isIntelliJ=true bash"`), but not with zsh for some reason.
  - I've also tried the following combinations with the same result :  `zsh -c "export isIntellij=true; zsh"`, `bash -c "export isIntellij=true; zsh"`, using the zsh `-i` flag

Is there any lead I've not explored ? Also, it should be noted that I can't update IntelliJ (this is my perpetual fallback license).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after fumbling around, I figured it out.

Basically, my 2nd attempt was on the right track. The only caveat : you have to restart intelliJ for it to update the value of the `isIntellij` variable.

Steps to reproduce :

- Add the following code to your .zshrc file :

  ```
  if [[ "$isIntelliJ" = "true" ]]; then
  #config for intelliJ execution
  else
  #config for regular execution
  fi
  ```
- Open IntelliJ, go in the `Tools>Terminal` settings
- Update the `Shell path` value to `wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-22.04 zsh -c "isIntelliJ=true zsh"`
- Restart IntelliJ

**Update:** It seems you have to do that for every existing project as otherwise IntelliJ will load the default wsl path, which is really tedious. I will update if I find a more definitive solution, as as far as I can tell, there is no xml file available for default terminal settings